# can't access Google-VR-SDK classes from nativescript

Tags: video, telerik, nativescript, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm trying to develop an app with Nativescript which embeds a 360 degree video player and streams the video from a node.js nginx reverse proxy server.

I did everything as described, created a package.json and a Podfile.
Then add the Google-VR-SDK through a plugin with tns plugin add command. 
My project builds.

I can't access any classes of Google-VR-SDK.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

The code i have to implement as javascript is this,

```
_videoView = [[GVRVideoView alloc] init];
_videoView.delegate = self;
_videoView.enableFullscreenButton = YES;
_videoView.enableCardboardButton = YES;
[_scrollView addSubview:_videoView];
```

Neither

```
`var _videoView = new GVRVideoView();`
```

nor

```
var _videoView = GVRVideoView.alloc().init();
```

is working.

I haven't required an extra module in my code. I also don't know what to require.

Comment: I would love to hear at least an idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google-VR-SDK libraries for Android are Java files (*.aar).
So basically what you need to do is to import your libraries in your project
and use the data conversion from Java to JavaScript.

What you are doing is the workflow for iOS Podfiles and Objective-C ...

Here you can find the concepts behind marshalling (data conversion
https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/java-to-js.html)

To use your **jar** or **aar** file what you need to do is to place it in your project ***platforms/android/libs/*** folder and from there you can access it with its API references.

For example (based on the [VR API](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/package-summary)):

```
var app = require("application");

var myVrVideoView = new com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView(app.android.context);
```

Overall I recommend that you get familiar with the workflow of creating a plugin described step by step at the following link : 
https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins.html